# Continuous Integration of a 1st Differenced Logged Series in R

Tags: r, integration, difference, continuous

I have a 1st differenced logged series that I need to convert back to the original level units. How do I do this in R?

Below is my data series and attempted code:

Original Series:

```
1.1, 2.6, 3.6, 4.8, 5.1, 6.0, 7.3, 8.8, 9.4, 10.5
```

Attempted Code:

```
o <- c(1.1, 2.6, 3.6, 4.8, 5.1, 6.0, 7.3, 8.8, 9.4, 10.5)
l <- log(o)
dl <- diff(l)

exp(diffinv(dl, differences = 1)) # Attempt to recover o
```

Current Output:

```
[1] 1.000000 2.363636 3.272727 4.363636 4.636364 5.454545 6.636364 8.000000 
[9] 8.545455 9.545455
```

Desired Output:

```
[1] 1.1 2.6 3.6 4.8 5.1 6.0 7.3 8.8
[9] 9.4 10.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to fully recover the original series without knowing its first element:

```
exp(diffinv(dl) + log(1.1))
# [1]  1.1  2.6  3.6  4.8  5.1  6.0  7.3  8.8  9.4 10.5
```

or

```
exp(cumsum(c(log(1.1), dl)))
# [1]  1.1  2.6  3.6  4.8  5.1  6.0  7.3  8.8  9.4 10.5
```

---

Let X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, X<sub>3</sub>, X<sub>4</sub> be the original series. Then ultimately you have

Z<sub>1</sub> = ln(X<sub>2</sub>) - ln(X<sub>1</sub>),

Z<sub>2</sub> = ln(X<sub>3</sub>) - ln(X<sub>2</sub>)

Z<sub>3</sub> = ln(X<sub>4</sub>) - ln(X<sub>3</sub>)

Given Z<sub>1</sub>, Z<sub>2</sub>, Z<sub>3</sub>, you wish to recover X<sub>1</sub>, X<sub>2</sub>, X<sub>3</sub>, X<sub>4</sub>. Then notice that

Z<sub>1</sub> = ln(X<sub>2</sub>) - ln(X<sub>1</sub>),

Z<sub>2</sub> + Z<sub>1</sub> = ln(X<sub>3</sub>) - ln(X<sub>1</sub>),

Z<sub>3</sub> + Z<sub>2</sub> + Z<sub>1</sub> = ln(X<sub>4</sub>) - ln(X<sub>1</sub>),

so that

Z<sub>1</sub> + ln(X<sub>1</sub>) = ln(X<sub>2</sub>),

Z<sub>2</sub> + Z<sub>1</sub> + ln(X<sub>1</sub>) = ln(X<sub>3</sub>),

Z<sub>3</sub> + Z<sub>2</sub> + Z<sub>1</sub> + ln(X<sub>1</sub>) = ln(X<sub>4</sub>),

and

exp(Z<sub>1</sub> + ln(X<sub>1</sub>)) = X<sub>2</sub>,

exp(Z<sub>2</sub> + Z<sub>1</sub> + ln(X<sub>1</sub>)) = X<sub>3</sub>,

exp(Z<sub>3</sub> + Z<sub>2</sub> + Z<sub>1</sub> + ln(X<sub>1</sub>)) = X<sub>4</sub>,

which is exactly what (more transparently than the first solution)

```
exp(cumsum(c(log(1.1), dl)))
```

does. As a consequence,

```
 exp(diffinv(dl))
```

alone works **only when the original series starts from** 1 = exp(0).

Thus, you must now the initial levels of the series as to recover it from any kind of differences, which is perfectly natural. Imagine that we only know how much you are going to earn and spend every day. At no point it's possible to say how much in total you have money without knowing the initial amount.

Comment: Great, this information was very helpful.

Now suppose, that I only know the forecasted values of the original series, which are also 1st differenced and logged, i.e.:

dlf <- (2.1, 3.5,  4.7,  5.0,  6.1,  7.4,  8.7,  9.5, 10.9)

Comment: @Darlene, I suppose then you want a forecasts for the original series in levels. The procedure is the same: `exp(cumsum(c(log(firstValueInLevels), forecasted)))`. The idea is that while you have predicted differences, you may still combine it with a known initial level.

Comment: Yes, I apologize, stackoverflow would not allow me to edit my question.

In my example, what is the firstValueInLevels?

Comment: @Darlene, in terms of your terminology, it looks like you want `exp(cumsum(c(log(o[1]), dlf)))`.

Comment: Yes, but in the second example of a forecasted series (dlf), I do not know the firstValueinLevels as it is a predicted series in 1st differenced, logged units.

Comment: @Darlene, a clarification before giving a full answer: you started with some series `o`, from it got `dl`, and then predicted **future** values `dlf`, is that right? (People sometimes mean different things by prediction.)

Comment: Yes, dlf are hypothetical predicted or forecasted values of o that are in 1st differenced, logged units.

Comment: @Darlene, it doesn't really sound like a yes to me... A typical example in practice would be (forget about logs for now): `o` is (2,4,1) for time periods 1, 2, 3; differences `d` are (2, -3) for period 2, 3; a single forecasted future difference `df` for time period 4 could be, say, 0. Then you may ask to what this 0 corresponds in terms of levels. Is that your situation and question?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely my question.

Comment: @Darlene, ok, then you want `o[length(o)] + exp(cumsum(dlf))`. Those are future predictions in levels. In my previous example it would mean that time period 4 prediction in levels is 1 + 0 = 1. Here `o` is the very initial series in levels, like (2,4,1) before.

Comment: @Darlene, actually I think I was wrong in my last comment and it should instead be `exp(cumsum(dlf) + log(o[length(o)]))`, sorry.